# Delete request works in postman but it is not working in my code , show 401.even sending headers as required

Tags: reactjs, api, flask, postman

```
const deleteList = (id) => {

const tk = localStorage.getItem("token");
console.log(tk)

const deleteId = {
    _id: `${id}`,
}
console.log(deleteId);
axios.delete(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/prospectlist`, deleteId, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ` + localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
        const apires = await response.data;
        const message = apires.message;
        alert(message);

    });
```

}

**Response gives as 401 unauthorized**
It is working fine in postman but not in this code.
Is there anything missed in the header.
I am using JWT for the authentication

Comment: Can you add the flask side of code that handles JWT authentication

Comment: Thank you , Bhavani Ravi for your response 
I managed to solve this issue , by adding id in the , api link
as http://127.0.0.1/list/${id}